# Using cocoon gem, but can't save data after first input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I've tried to implement cocoon in my application, but having trouble saving data after the first input field.

I tried following the example, but no luck.

I'm able to save the first field into database, but nothing happens on the other fields when I add more.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :project_name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  <div id="tasks">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |g| %>
      <%= render 'task_fields', :f => g %>
    <% end%>

    <%= link_to_add_association 'add task', f, :tasks %>
  </div>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**_task_fields.html.erb**

```
<li class="control-group nested-fields">
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.label :task %>
    <%= f.text_field :task %>
  </div>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove task", f %>
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
params.require(:project).permit(
  :user_id, :project_name, 
  tasks_attributes: [:id, :task, :_destroy])
```

And I added:

```
//= require cocoon
```

in `application.js`

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

**Task Model**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I think I got this correct? I'm able to click on "add task" link and a new field pops up, but those new fields doesn't save.

---

**EDIT** from POST in console

```
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {
       "utf8"=>"✓", 
       "authenticity_token"=>"blah", 
       "project"=>{"project_name"=>"cocoon test", 
       "tasks_attributes"=>{
               "0"=>{"task"=>"fix this!", 
                     "_destroy"=>"false"
                    }}}, 
       "commit"=>"Create Project"}
  (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("project_name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["project_name", "cocoon test"], ["created_at", "2015-07-15 03:26:09.444377"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-15 03:26:09.444377"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("task", "project_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["task", "fix this!"], ["project_id", 8], ["created_at", "2015-07-15 03:26:09.450324"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-15 03:26:09.450324"]]
   (8.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/projects/8
Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 10.4ms)
```

---

**EDIT 2** posting project controller methods `create` and `new`

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def new
  @project = Project.new
  @project.tasks.build
end
```

Comment: Please provide output from console from POST action generated by form with new tasks. (after you click on create/save button)

Comment: Next thing you're missing div with id **tasks** arround simple_fields_for :)

Comment: @JanStrnádek thanks, I edited my post to show POST, it looks like its only getting 1 task attribute. Why is this happening? Also, I updated my view to have the div, which solved another issue I had with css, thanks for that.

Comment: Can you post your controller code specially `new`, `create` methods?

Comment: @Pavan hello! I edited to show my create and new methods.

Comment: Your code is fine and the server log says that the tasks attributes are inserted into the tasks table. I see nothing wrong here.

Comment: @hellomello Try to look into generated cocon code (task nested form fields - in id fields, it looks like it sends just once with id = 0 and its overwritten by the next fields..  Next thing try to look in javascript console, any messages here?

Comment: @JanStrnádek ahh!! it worked! I think I just had to restart my server because of the div id....

Comment: @Pavan Hi! It worked, I had to restart my server for it to work after adding an div id to my simple_fields_for

Comment: Ok, thats kind a weird why you have to restart your development environment after adding simple div with id?

Comment: @JanStrnádek I have no clue... this coding thing is mind-boggling to me lol